# Как увеличить высоту navigation bar в iOS11?

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigationbar

До iOS 11 для изменения высоты navBar'a отлично работало такое решение:

```
const CGFloat height = 80;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,
self.view.frame.size.width,height)];
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34850109

но в Xcode 9 + iOS 11, оно больше не работает

Comment: Может будет лучше использовать Large titles?

Comment: хочется увеличить высоту навбара именно на произвольное значение ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Создайте класс-наследник от UINavigationBar. Переопределите метод `layoutSubViews` c нужной вам высотой:

**Objective-C:**

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    CGFloat navBarHeigh = 100;
    CGFloat heightDelta = (([UIScreen mainScreen].nativeBounds.size.height == 2436) ? 44.0 : 20.0);
    for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        if ([NSStringFromClass([subview class]) containsString:@"BarBackground"]) {
            CGRect subViewFrame = subview.frame;
            subViewFrame.origin.y = -heightDelta;
            subViewFrame.size.height = navBarHeigh + heightDelta;
            [subview setFrame: subViewFrame];
        }
    }
}
```

**Swift:**

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    let navBarHeight: CGFloat = 100
    let heightDelta: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436 ? 44 : 20
    for subview in subviews {
        if String(describing: subview).contains("BarBackground") {
            subview.frame.origin.y = -heightDelta
            subview.frame.size.height = navBarHeight + heightDelta
        }
    }
}
```

Укажите его для UINavigationController:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А для чего ‘let heightDelta: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.nativeBounds.height == 2436 ? 44 : 20’ ?

Comment: @Son'kaV для iPhone X. У него по радиусу скругления высота статус бара 44.